# Slow VBA macro using nested loops and autofilter to consolidate select data from 2 worksheets into 1

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have two large worksheets that I need to consolidate select data into one worksheet. Both worksheets contain about 80K+ rows, the output is expected to be in that range as well. At this point in time, the code works, but it is extremely slow. I don't actually know how long it actually takes to run on the full data set. I have let is run for 8+ hours without having it finish.

The procedure uses a `for each` loop to move through all the rows of the primary worksheet `wsICD10` and selects all rows of concern (based on the criteria in the `if` statement) and logs the `LOS_Group` for use later in the VBA autofilter of the  `wsDUNST15` worksheet. I use two nested `for` loops to exhaustively extract all the data from the `wsDUNST15`. Once all my variables are full I write them to my new workbook and move on to the next record of interest in my `wsICD10` with the `for each` loop.

My guess is the combination of nested loops and auto-filtering the large worksheets is an inefficient way to complete my task. But I'm unaware of another way to select a worksheet row using multiple criteria.

```
Public Sub ICD10DataSet()


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Create ICD-10-CM/PCS data set
'
'ICD10_Type | ageCategory | DiagnosisProcedure_Category | ICD10_Code | LOS_Group | AVG_Stay
'
'
' This will use Truven October, 2017 data files
'
' By Trevor Pye
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim ICD10_Data As Worksheet
Dim wsICD10 As Worksheet
Dim wsDUNST15 As Worksheet
Dim ICD_Cell As Range
Dim ICD_Range As Range
Dim ICD10_Type As String
Dim AgeCat As Integer
Dim diagProced_Cat As Integer
Dim ICD10_Code As String
Dim LOS_Group As String
Dim AVG_Stay As Double

Dim startTime As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
startTime = Time



Set wb = Workbooks("LOS_WorkBookICD-10_201710.xlsm")
Set wbData = Workbooks.Add
Set wsICD10 = wb.Worksheets("ICD10Full")
Set wsDUNST15 = wb.Worksheets("DUNST15")
Set wsOUNST15 = wb.Worksheets("OUNST15")

Set ICD_Range = wsICD10.Range("A2", wsICD10.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))
Set ICD_Cell = wsICD10.Range("A2")

Set ICD10_Data = wbData.Sheets(1)
ICD10_Data.Range("A1") = Format(startTime, "HH:MM:SS")

'---- Start Header with block -------
With ICD10_Data
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = "ICD10_Type"
    .Cells(2, 2).Value = "ageCategory"
    .Cells(2, 3).Value = "DiagnosisProcedure_Category"
    .Cells(2, 4).Value = "ICD10_Code"
    .Cells(2, 5).Value = "LOS_Group"
    .Cells(2, 6).Value = "AVG_Stay"
End With
'---- Header Header with block -------

t = 3 '<--- starting row number

' define ICD_Type, ICD10_Code, LOS_Group
'-----Start ICD10 Code loop ---- 
For Each ICD_Cell In ICD_Range

    If ICD_Cell.Offset(, 4) = "@" Or ICD_Cell.Offset(-1, 2) = ICD_Cell.Offset(0, 2) Or ICD_Cell.Offset(, 12) = "" Then
        GoTo SkipCodeBlock '<--- Row not of interest, skip to next row
    Else
        ICD10_Code = ICD_Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value 
        LOS_Group = ICD_Cell.Offset(, 12) 
        ICD10_Type = ICD_Cell.Value  
    End If

'-------Start of nested diagnosis Loops ----------  
    If ICD10_Type = "D" Then
         For i = 1 To 5
                AgeCat = i ' <--- setting the Age category integer value
                 For j = 1 To 4
                     Select Case j ' <--- setting the diagnosis integer value
                        Case 1
                            diagProced_Cat = 0
                        Case 2
                            diagProced_Cat = 1
                        Case 3
                            diagProced_Cat = 3
                        Case Else
                            diagProced_Cat = 4
                    End Select
                    With wsDUNST15.UsedRange '<-- retrieving the row of interest
                        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=LOS_Group
                        .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=diagProced_Cat
                        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=AgeCat
                    End With
                    AVG_Stay = 
(wsDUNST15.Range(wsDUNST15.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp), 
"H2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value)/10
                    wsDUNST15.ShowAllData ' <---Resetting filters
                    With ICD10_Data ' log Results
                        finalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            .Cells(t, 1).Value = ICD10_Type
                            .Cells(t, 2).Value = AgeCat
                            .Cells(t, 3).Value = diagProced_Cat
                            .Cells(t, 4).Value = ICD10_Code
                            .Cells(t, 5).Value = "'" & LOS_Group
                            .Cells(t, 6).Value = AVG_Stay
                    End With
                     t = t + 1
                    Next j
            Next i
    Else
        GoTo complete
    End If
'-------End of nested diagnosis Loops -------   

SkipCodeBlock:
Next ICD_Cell
'------End ICD10 Code loop -----
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

complete:
endTime = Time

ICD10_Data.Range("b1") = Format(endTime, "HH:MM:SS")

MsgBox "Procedure Complete!"
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to get a quality answer you should post some sample data and sample output and any Worksheet formulas that you may be using.  I think that you mentioned a result set of +10K before the question was edited.  That implies autofiltering the data +10k times. If that is the case give up on this approach.  It work probably take less than a minute to process all the data in arrays.

Comment: I will add sample data later today.

Comment: The Dataset I'm working with is too big for excel, it exceeds the 1,048,576 row max. I probably looking for a Database solution thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any data to work with so it likely needs debugged, but the general idea is to use sorting and cell formulas to do more of the heavy lifting than `AutoFilter`:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Create ICD-10-CM/PCS data set
'
'ICD10_Type | ageCategory | DiagnosisProcedure_Category | ICD10_Code | LOS_Group | AVG_Stay
'
'
' This will use Truven October, 2017 data files
'
' By Trevor Pye
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub ICD10DataSet()
'    Dim ICD10_Type As String
'    Dim AgeCat As Integer
'    Dim diagProced_Cat As Integer
'    Dim ICD10_Code As String
'    Dim LOS_Group As String
'    Dim AVG_Stay As Double

    Dim startTime As Double, endTime As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    startTime = Time
    Debug.Print "Started: " & Format(startTime, "HH:MM:SS")

    Dim wbData As Workbook, ICD10_Data As Worksheet
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Add
    Set ICD10_Data = wbData.Sheets(1)

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsICD10 As Worksheet, wsDUNST15 As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("LOS_WorkBookICD-10_201710.xlsm")
    Set wsICD10 = wb.Worksheets("ICD10Full")
    Set wsDUNST15 = wb.Worksheets("DUNST15")
'    Set wsOUNST15 = wb.Worksheets("OUNST15")

'    Dim ICD_Range As Range
'    Set ICD_Range = wsICD10.Range("A2", wsICD10.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))

    '---- Copy ICD10 data
    wsICD10.UsedRange.Columns(1).Copy ICD10_Data.Range("A1")
    wsICD10.UsedRange.Columns(3).Copy ICD10_Data.Range("D1")
    wsICD10.UsedRange.Columns(13).Copy ICD10_Data.Range("E1")

    '---- Filter ICD10 data
    Dim ToRange As Range, ICD_Cell As Range
    Set ToRange = ICD10_Data.UsedRange.Columns(2).Offset(1, 0)
    Set ToRange = ToRange.Resize(ToRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    Set ICD_Cell = wsICD10.Range("A2")
    ToRange.Formula = "=OR(" & _
       ICD_Cell.Offset(, 4).Address(False, True, xlA1, True) & "=""@""," & _
       ICD_Cell.Offset(-1, 2).Address(False, True, xlA1, True) & "=" & ICD_Cell.Offset(0, 2).Address(False, True, xlA1, True) & "," & _
       ICD_Cell.Offset(, 12).Address(False, True, xlA1, True) & "=""""," & _
       ICD_Cell.Address(False, True, xlA1, True) & "<>""D""" & _
    ")"
    ToRange.Copy
    ToRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ICD10_Data.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ICD10_Data.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ICD10_Data.Range("B1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ICD10_Data.Sort
        .SetRange ICD10_Data.UsedRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ToRange.Find(What:="true", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        ICD10_Data.Range(ICD10_Data.Cells(f.Row, 1), ICD10_Data.Cells(ICD10_Data.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    ICD10_Data.Columns(2).ClearContents

    '---- Start Header with block -------
    With ICD10_Data
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "ICD10_Type"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "ageCategory"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "DiagnosisProcedure_Category"
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = "ICD10_Code"
        .Cells(1, 5).Value = "LOS_Group"
        .Cells(1, 6).Value = "AVG_Stay"
    End With
    '---- Header Header with block -------

    '---- Additional Filter
'    ICD10_Data.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes

    Dim DupeRange As Range
    Set DupeRange = ICD10_Data.UsedRange
    Set DupeRange = DupeRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(DupeRange.Rows.Count - 1, DupeRange.Columns.Count)
    Set ToRange = DupeRange.Columns(1).Cells(DupeRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0)

    '---- Expand ICD10 data by AgeCat 1 to 5
    'ICD10_Data.Range("B2") = [1..5]
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        DupeRange.Columns(2).Value = i
        If i < 5 Then
            DupeRange.Copy ToRange
            Set ToRange = ToRange.Offset(DupeRange.Rows.Count, 0)
        End If
    Next i

    '---- Expand ICD10 data by diagProced_Cat {0,1,3,4}
    'ICD10_Data.Range("C2") = [0,1,3,4]
    Dim diagProced_Cat As Variant
    diagProced_Cat = Array(0, 1, 3, 4)
    Set DupeRange = ICD10_Data.UsedRange
    Set DupeRange = DupeRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(DupeRange.Rows.Count - 1, DupeRange.Columns.Count)
    Set ToRange = DupeRange.Columns(1).Cells(DupeRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0)
    For i = LBound(diagProced_Cat) To UBound(diagProced_Cat)
        DupeRange.Columns(3).Value = diagProced_Cat(i)
        If i < UBound(diagProced_Cat) Then
            DupeRange.Copy ToRange
            Set ToRange = ToRange.Offset(DupeRange.Rows.Count, 0)
        End If
    Next i

    '---- Calculate AVG_Stay via cell formula
    Dim LOS_GroupAddr As String, diagProced_CatAddr As String, AgeCatAddr As String, StayAddr As String
    LOS_GroupAddr = wsDUNST15.UsedRange.Columns(4).Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
    diagProced_CatAddr = wsDUNST15.UsedRange.Columns(5).Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
    AgeCatAddr = wsDUNST15.UsedRange.Columns(6).Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
    StayAddr = wsDUNST15.UsedRange.Columns(8).Address(True, True, xlA1, True)

    Set ToRange = ICD10_Data.UsedRange.Columns(6).Offset(1, 0)
    Set ToRange = ToRange.Resize(ToRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    ToRange.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT((" & LOS_GroupAddr & "=$E2)*(" & diagProced_CatAddr & "=$C2)*(" & AgeCatAddr & "=$B2)*(" & StayAddr & "))/10"
    ToRange.Copy
    ToRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ICD10_Data.Rows(1).Insert xlShiftDown
    ICD10_Data.Range("A1") = Format(startTime, "HH:MM:SS")
    endTime = Time
    ICD10_Data.Range("B1") = Format(endTime, "HH:MM:SS")
    Debug.Print "Finished: " & Format(endTime, "HH:MM:SS")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'complete:

    MsgBox "Procedure Complete!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks promising, there are some bugs that I will work through and will publish the new version when complete.

Answer (score 0):

SQL version based on comment:

> I'm probably looking for a database solution

Since you're in Excel I'm guessing you'd be able to try a MS-Access solution

1. Import ICD10Full and DUNST15 as tables
2. Manually Create the two Tables [AgeCats] and [DiagProcs]:

```
AgeCats:         DiagProcs:
  ageCategory       DiagnosisProcedure_Category
  -----------       ---------------------------
  1                 0
  2                 1
  3                 3
  4                 4
  5
```

3. Create query [010 Filter ICD10Full], Note: ColumnE is referred to in your code `If ICD_Cell.Offset(, 4) = "@"` but never given a name

```sql
SELECT distinct ICD10_Type, ICD10_Code, LOS_Group
FROM [ICD10Full]
WHERE
   ColumnE <> '@'
   AND LOS_Group <> ''
   AND ICD10_Type = 'D';
```

4. Create Query [020 ICD10Reduced]

```sql
SELECT ICD10_Type,ageCategory,DiagnosisProcedure_Category,ICD10_Code,LOS_Group
FROM [010 Filter ICD10Full],[AgeCats],[DiagProcs];
```

5. Create Query [030 ICD10 Summary], Note: I've left it as `LEFT JOIN` to match your original code, but you'll probably want `INNER JOIN` to reduce the nothingness, also ColumnH is never given a name in your code `wsDUNST15.Range("H1048576")`

```sql
SELECT
   ICD10.ICD10_Type
   ,ICD10.ageCategory
   ,ICD10.DiagnosisProcedure_Category
   ,ICD10.ICD10_Code
   ,ICD10.LOS_Group
   ,Avg(DUNS15.ColumnH) AS AVG_Stay
FROM [020 ICD10Reduced] AS ICD10 LEFT JOIN [DUNS15] ON
   ICD10.geCategory = DUNS15.ageCategory
   AND ICD10.DiagnosisProcedure_Category = DUNS15.DiagnosisProcedure_Category
   AND ICD10.LOS_Group = DUNS15.LOS_Group
GROUP BY
   ICD10.ICD10_Type
   ,ICD10.ageCategory
   ,ICD10.DiagnosisProcedure_Category
   ,ICD10.ICD10_Code
   ,ICD10.LOS_Group;
```

Other databases (SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) would have different formatting of the SQL code, but the steps would more or less remain the same.